# Cleaning up Photos.app with AppleScript

Tags: automator, photos.app

I am trying to figure out if the following is possible using AppleScript - I am much more used to scripting on Linux / PowerShell.

I have a load of duplicated images in my Photos.app library, for each photo I have the original 'Live' photo and a static .JPG photo because I didn't realise for years that Photo Stream didn't support Live photos.

For example, I have a 2 photos with the following filenames:

```
IMG_0333.HEIC (live)
IMG_0333.JPG (static)
```

I would like to use AppleScript to interate through a selection of photos, and if there is a filename with both .HEIC and .JPG extentions, delete the .JPG one.

This would be trivial on the command line if I were just dealing with flat files, but I don't know where to start with AppleScript or Automator!

This is what I have so far, the commented parts are the ones I am having trouble with!

```
tell application "Photos"
    set theseItems to get selection
    repeat with i from 1 to the count of theseItems
        set thisItem to item i of theseItems
        set PhotoFilename to filename of thisItem
        log PhotoFilename
        if PhotoFilename ends with "HEIC" then
            // Strip off the .HEIC part to get <filename>
            // does the <filename>.JPG exist in the selection?
            // if so, delete it
            log PhotoFilename
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: **.HEIC** _files_ are not "live" and are as static as **.JPG** _files_ are. It's the **.MOV** _files_ that are the "live" part of the _set_.

Comment: @user3439894 you are technically correct (the best kind of correct) but whatever Photos.app is doing in the background, it's presenting the .HEIC image as a live photo, so I guess the .MOV part is hidden by the application. So what I need to do still stands

Comment: This may depend of what version go **macOS** you are running and the version of **Photos**, however, as an example, in **macOS Catalina** in **Photos** using **AppleScript** you cannot delete individual _files_, only **Albums** and **Folders**. As these objects are virtual constructs, you are not deleting the original _files_ of the _files_ within them. From the **AppleScript** dictionary for **Photos**... **delete** _v_ : Delete an object. Only albums and folders can be deleted. **delete** `album` or `folder` : The album or folder to delete.

Comment: Well, damn. That's a shame! I am running Catalina. If the Photos 'API' doesn't expose a photo delete function then I guess there is not an awful lot I can do. Thank you for the help!

Comment: A useful solution for the missing "delete":  instead of deleting with your script (that is dangerous anyways), better create an album of all the images that should be deleted.  Then in Photos.app check the content of the album, mark all and command-right-click on one of the photos, the last menu point is "delete".  (this is similar to http://scripts.mit.edu/~birge/blog/applescript-program-to-find-duplicate-jpgs-in-apple-photos/)